# Need help loading a package into an Anaconda3 environment TIA

Tags: installation, python, anaconda

Where I'm at:

I used "pip install fix-yahoo-finance" in the Anaconda prompt to load the package from https://pypi.org/project/fix-yahoo-finance/ into the general site-packages folder, then

Then I moved the "fix-yahoo-finance" folder into the "C:\Users\\Anaconda3\envs\\Lib\site-packages" folder.  This "fix-yahoo-finance" folder contains

1. "*pycache*" folder with a **init**.cpython-37.pyc file
2. A "fix_yahoo_finance-0.0.22.dist-info" folder with 7 files, and
3. A "**init**.py" file.

I have tried everything I can think of (6 hours of work) to get this package to show up in the installed list of packages in Navigator.

HOW DO I GET FROM THERE INTO THE LIST OF INSTALLED PACKAGES THAT NAVIGATOR SEES?

My general Python setup is Anaconda3 and PyCharm. I set up a PyCharm environment using my Anaconda3 environment.  My script and setup was working fine until I had a major equipment failure followed by a catastrophic Windows 10 failure.  I'm an "old" (76, 15 years with Python scripts) "newbie".

P.S. My DIY hardware setup is brand new (now) and Windows has been clean installed (5 times!!!)  Sorry for the rant!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem:

Actually the main reason my script no longer would run was due to a PATH setting problem in PyCharm that is being addressed in their next update. If others have this problem, there is a pre-release version of PyCharm available "https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/" that fixes the problem.

In my case, it showed up as a "Missing required dependencies ['numpy']".  Once my script hit this problem, it cascaded into a bunch of other secondary problems.  Ergo my original question.